# Why can I not obtain a page `access_token` for my OpenGraph object?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-access-token

I have a [very simple page](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3618086/willet/fb_admin2.html) which includes the necessary OpenGraph tags to create an OpenGraph object when liked, and I would like to be able to post as that page. From what I understand, I require an `access_token` for the page and I can obtain it by either visiting the OpenGraph page...

```
https://graphs.facebook.com/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token
```

...Or from my account...

```
https://graphs.facebook.com/me/accounts
```

...with a proper user `access_token`.

However, if I check either of these, there is no `access_token` for my page; if I check the pages for my account, it's not even in the list.

I have made sure to include an `fb:admins` tag on the page with my user id, and I have also liked the page ([as described in 'Page Administration' in the Open Graph documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/)).

**Why can I not obtain a page `access_token` for my OpenGraph object?**

Comment: You can not get a page access token for Open Graph objects – that’s just available for Facebook pages. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/#publishing says you need an _app_ access token to publish updates to users who liked your Open Graph object.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. I wasn't sure if that was the case or not. If you could list your answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why can I not obtain a page access_token for my OpenGraph object?

You can not get a page access token for Open Graph objects – that’s just available for Facebook pages.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/#publishing says you need an app access token to publish updates to users who liked your Open Graph object.